# r - count number of identical rows

Tags: r, matrix, count, row

I hope this is not a duplicate question (did my best to see if it was already asked). I have a data frame and would like to count how many rows are identical.

```
df = data.frame(ID = c("id1", "id2", "id3", "id4", "id5", "id6", "id7", "id8", "id9"),
            Val1 = c("A", "B", "C", "A", "A", "B", "D", "C", "D"),
            Val2 = c("B", "C", NA, "B", "B", "D", "E", "D", "E"),
            Val3 = c("C", NA, NA, "C", "C", "B", NA, NA,NA),
            Val4 = c("D", NA, NA, "E", "D", NA, NA, NA, NA))
> df
   ID Val1 Val2 Val3 Val4
1 id1    A    B    C    D
2 id2    B    C <NA> <NA>
3 id3    C <NA> <NA> <NA>
4 id4    A    B    C    E
5 id5    A    B    C    D
6 id6    B    D    B <NA>
7 id7    D    E <NA> <NA>
8 id8    C    D <NA> <NA>
9 id9    D    E <NA> <NA>
```

So for this example I expect that the return would be `A  B  C  D  2`, `D  E  2`, `B  C  <NA>  <NA>  1` and so on.. 
Tried with `table` but I get an `Error in table(type_table) : attempt to make a table with >= 2^31 elements` and my df has "only" ~140K rows. I want to apply this on a much larger dataset. Tried with `summarise` also but probably I do not know how to apply it correctly. Is `aggregate` an option? Thank you

Comment: Try `table(do.call(paste, df[-1]))` maybe

Comment: Hmm.. looks like it's working but did not try on a big dataset yet. Any idea about the computational complexity of that function?

Comment: `do.call` is very efficient and calls `paste` only once. You could switch to `data.table` if you afraid of `table`. Something like `library(data.table); setDT(df)[, .N, by = .(Uniques = do.call(paste, df[, -1, with = FALSE]))]`

Comment: OK. Cool. I'm not afraid of using table, I just do not know which one will crash first if I use it on millions of rows. I guess will figure it out soon enough :] Thank you. Can you make it as a formal answer so I can select it.

Comment: You can try to `duplicated(df[-1])` which returns a logical vector saying if corresponding line is a duplicate

Comment: @clemlaflemme it won't work because they need *all* the dupes and they need to separate them too.

Comment: @DavidArenburg : `apply(df[-1][!duplicated(df[-1]),], 1, function(v) {sum(duplicated(rbind(v,df[-1][duplicated(df[-1]),]))) + 1})` but I agree your solution is better

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reason why `table` isn't working is because it treats each column separately and tries to find by element combinations instead of by row combinations.

You can try using the `do.call(paste(` combination in order to paste elements by row and run `table` over it

```
table(do.call(paste, df[-1]))
# A B C D    A B C E  B C NA NA   B D B NA  C D NA NA C NA NA NA  D E NA NA 
#       2          1          1          1          1          1          2
```

If `table` isn't efficient enough, we can try with `.N` from `data.table` instead

```
library(data.table) 
setDT(df)[, .N, by = c(names(df)[-1])]
#    Val1 Val2 Val3 Val4 N
# 1:    A    B    C    D 2
# 2:    B    C   NA   NA 1
# 3:    C   NA   NA   NA 1
# 4:    A    B    C    E 1
# 5:    B    D    B   NA 1
# 6:    D    E   NA   NA 2
# 7:    C    D   NA   NA 1
```

Answer (score 0):

With `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
df[, dups := 1:.N, setdiff(names(df), "ID")]
df[, .SD[.N], setdiff(names(df), c("ID", "dups"))][dups != 1]
```

Group by everything except `ID`, index items within groups of duplicates, then select the last row in each group (when the duplication index isn't `1`).